# How can you make a second contextual filter completely optional

Tags: views

In views, is it possible to have two contextual filters, making one mandatory (return no results if not supplied), and the other optional? I'm using a php filter to get the group id for the `og_group_ref` field, and it works well, but then I add another filter on another field, and I need to be able to check only on certain pages (that provide the param in the url), or else, just return all record.  I tried a conditional for the second filter, like

```
    if(some test){
      return field_value;
   }
    else{
      return 'all';
   }
```

That didn't help either.